# How do I get my code to output the total price of the users vend?

Tags: c#, dictionary, struct, sum, numbers

I am currently trying to make  a little vending machine program that takes the users selection of item, asks how many they would like of said item, then find the total price of the vend and give them the correct amount of change.However, I cant seem to get this code to output the totalprice of the vend. Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

```
namespace ugh
{
  class Program
  {
    struct VendingItem
    {
        public string name;
        public double price;
        public string code;
    }
```

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string selection = "";
        double price = 0;
        double finalCost = 0;
        int numOfItem = 0;
        bool Yorn = true;
        Dictionary<string, VendingItem> snacks = new Dictionary<string, VendingItem>();
        VendingItem v;

        //snacks
        v.name = "Mars Bar";
        v.price = 1.30;
        v.code = "A1";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Milky Way";
        v.price = 1.30;
        v.code = "A2";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Double Decker";
        v.price = 1.30;
        v.code = "A3";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Kit Kat";
        v.price = 1.30;
        v.code = "A4";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Dairy Milk";
        v.price = 1.30;
        v.code = "A5";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Pringles Original";
        v.price = 1.70;
        v.code = "A6";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Pringles Salt and Vinegar";
        v.price = 1.70;
        v.code = "A7";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Pringles Cheese and Onion";
        v.price = 1.70;
        v.code = "A8";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Pringles Texas BBQ";
        v.price = 1.70;
        v.code = "A9";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Pringles Prawn Cocktail";
        v.price = 1.70;
        v.code = "A10";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        //drinks

        v.name = "Water";
        v.price = 1.00;
        v.code = "A11";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Red Bull";
        v.price = 1.35;
        v.code = "A12";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Monster";
        v.price = 1.35;
        v.code = "A13";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Fanta Orange";
        v.price = 1.20;
        v.code = "A14";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);

        v.name = "Fanta Fruit Twist";
        v.price = 1.20;
        v.code = "A15";
        snacks.Add(v.code, v);
```

```
        //outputting the name, code and price of each item in the list
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, VendingItem> item in snacks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Snack: {0} -\nCode: {1}\nPrice: £{2}\n\n", item.Value.name, item.Value.code, item.Value.price);
        }            
        //calling the vendSelection method using a new string selection and the dictionary snacks as the parameters
        vendSelection(selection, snacks);
```

```
        //find out how many they would like
        Console.WriteLine("How many of this item would you like?");
        numOfItem = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //get the price of item at location of user selection
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, VendingItem> item in snacks)
        {
            price = item.Value.price.CompareTo(item.Value.code.CompareTo(selection));
        }
        totalPrice(price, numOfItem);
        Console.WriteLine(price);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

```
    //method for taking user input and comparing it to the code of the snack/drink
    static string vendSelection(string x, Dictionary<string, VendingItem> snacks)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Please enter the code that corresponds with the item you would like: ");
       x = Console.ReadLine();
       bool YorN = true;           
       while (YorN == true)
       {             
           if (snacks.ContainsKey(x))
           {                                     
               YorN = false;                    
           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("That is not an item in the list. Please enter another selection: ");
               x = Console.ReadLine();
           }               
       }
       return x;
    }
```

```
    //method for calculating price
    static double totalPrice(double price, int number)
    {
        return price * number;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get an output of whatever the total will be but instead all i'm getting is the number of the item that I input, can anyone suggest a way to go about fixing this issue?

Comment: In your code you are not displaying the result anywhere. Can you share the sample input, actual output and expected output ?

Comment: okay. Input1: "A13" Output: Nothing expected. Input2: "5" Output: "1"  Expected: "6.75"

Comment: You're overwriting the price with CompareTo, and ignoring the return value of the `totalPrice()` method.

Comment: how do i get that price then? The compareTo line is meant to find the price of the user selected item but i don't think it's right. I'm quite new to c# if you can't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is over complicated and a little hard to read, so I've re-written it. Try this instead.
I've removed a number of unnecessary declarations and methods and got a working solution for you. Any questions, just ask.

```
public class Program
{
    public struct VendingItem
    {
        public string name;
        public double price;
        public string code;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<VendingItem> stockCatalog = CatalogData();

        // Show the catalog to the user
        stockCatalog.ForEach(i => {
            Console.WriteLine($"Snack: {i.name}, Code: {i.code}, Price: £{i.price}");
        });

        // Get an item selection from the user
        VendingItem selection = GetSelection(stockCatalog);

        // Get a quantity from the user
        Console.WriteLine("How many of this item would you like?");
        int numOfItem = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double totalValue = selection.price * numOfItem;
        Console.WriteLine($"Your total cost is {totalValue}.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Get a selection from the user, if the user selection doesn't match an item in the catalog, ask again until it does.
    static VendingItem GetSelection(List<VendingItem> vendingItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the code that corresponds with the item you would like: ");
        string itemCode = Console.ReadLine();

        if (vendingItems.Any(i => i.code == itemCode))
        {
            return vendingItems.First(i => i.code == itemCode);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is not an item in the list.");
            return GetSelection(vendingItems);
        }

    }

    public static List<VendingItem> CatalogData()
    {
        List<VendingItem> vendingItems = new List<VendingItem>();

        // Add food items
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A1", price = 1.30, name = "Mars Bar" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A2", price = 1.30, name = "Milky Way" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A3", price = 1.30, name = "Double Decker" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A4", price = 1.30, name = "Kit Kat" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A5", price = 1.30, name = "Dairy Milk" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A6", price = 1.70, name = "Pringles Original" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A7", price = 1.70, name = "Pringles Salt and Vinegar" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A8", price = 1.70, name = "Pringles Cheese and Onion" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A9", price = 1.70, name = "Pringles Texas BBQ" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A10", price = 1.70, name = "Pringles Prawn Cocktail" });

        // Add drink items
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A11", price = 1.00, name = "Water" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A12", price = 1.35, name = "Red Bull" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A13", price = 1.35, name = "Monster" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A14", price = 1.20, name = "Fanta Orange" });
        vendingItems.Add(new VendingItem { code = "A15", price = 1.20, name = "Fanta Fruit Twist" });

        // Send back the catalog collection
        return vendingItems;
    }
}
```

Using a dictionary..

```
public class Program
{
    public struct VendingItem
    {
        public string name;
        public double price;
        public string code;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, VendingItem> stockDictionary = CatalogDataDictionary();

        // Show the catalog to the user
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, VendingItem> i in stockDictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Snack: {i.Value.name}, Code: {i.Value.code}, Price: £{i.Value.price}");
        }

        // Get an item selection from the user
        VendingItem selection = GetSelection(stockDictionary);

        // Get a quantity from the user
        Console.WriteLine("How many of this item would you like?");
        int numOfItem = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double totalValue = selection.price * numOfItem;
        Console.WriteLine($"Your total cost is {totalValue}.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Get a selection from the user, if the user selection doesn't match an item in the catalog, ask again until it does.
    static VendingItem GetSelection(Dictionary<string, VendingItem> vendingItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the code that corresponds with the item you would like: ");
        string itemCode = Console.ReadLine();

        if (vendingItems.ContainsKey(itemCode))
        {
            return vendingItems.First(i => i.Key == itemCode).Value;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is not an item in the list.");
            return GetSelection(vendingItems);
        }

    }

    public static Dictionary<string, VendingItem> CatalogDataDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<string, VendingItem> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, VendingItem>();

        // Add the food items
        keyValuePairs.Add("A1", new VendingItem() { code = "A1", price = 1.30, name = "Mars Bar" });

        return keyValuePairs;
    }
}
```

In both examples, the process of getting a number of items is an over-simplification and prone to throwing errors should the user enter a non-numeric value.
In reality, you should use a method similar to `GetSelection()` that returns `INT` and use that method to verify the input is a valid numeric value (min, max etc..) before passing it back to the main method.

For the purposes of a basic demonstration, the above is adequate.

Comment: although this is useful, i would like to stick t using a dictionary in the code, and the solution doesn't seem complicated, i just don't know the ins and outs of the problem

Comment: The same solution can be applied to the use of a dictionary as well. You just have to understandard the pattern you're using. In both cases I always return the `VendingItem` following a section which gives you access to the price to do with what you like. This is a far more robust solution and allows you to make code changes without much hassle.
Also, if you find an answer useful, please do mark it as such.

Comment: I have, however i cannot upvote it as i don't have more over 15 rep on here unfortunately. Thank you for the solution though!